# AWS large sized EC2 are automatically created and I'm charged above $2500

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I don't know what is happening with my AWS account. I was using Github $150 student pack on my AWS account.

I hardly created any EC2 instances on my AWS account. But now I'm fed up of **terminating** large sized EC2 instances which are automatically created in my account.

And all of above, I'm charged $2871.

Any solution, please? What measure can I take to stop being charged? I had contacted AWS support but they said to wait for 24 hours.

P.S. - I use my parents credit card.

[image]
[image]

Comment: FWIW, aws is normally very generous when it comes to costs created by misconfiguration, especially for students.

Comment: Did you run any program? Do you have a process currently running on your machine? There is not enough information in your question and it will likely be closed.

Comment: Check your autoscaling group on EC2 immediately. It looks like they're being automatically created.

Comment: @sm4 Yes, I do have a website hosted on EC2 free tier. Since yesterday, I'm charged highly on my account. Now, all the things are under control. I had deleted everything I found on my AWS account.

Comment: @Deif possibly auto scaling would not be the cause. Instances are automatically created after few minutes I delete them. Every time 6 x-large instances are created. Now, I'm broke.

Comment: It's an autoscaling group as that's the only thing that can cause instances to be automatically created. If you've removed everything from your account and they've stopped then you will have removed it.

Comment: Change any keys immediately - it's possible that your credentials have leaked and people are spinning up instances.  Also check if additional users and/or credentials have been created.  When this happened to a colleague of mine he had to delete the account and create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that somebody has obtained your credentials and are using your account without permission (eg for Bitcoin mining).

I recommend that you **contact AWS Customer Service immediately** (*NOT* Customer Support) and tell them that you suspect fraudulent access on your account. [Select "Billing and Account" enquiries](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/).

Some other things to check:

- Confirm that you have no Auto Scaling groups (in the Amazon EC2 console)
- Confirm that no other Users or Roles exist in the IAM console
- [Delete your Access Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html) associated with your existing Users
- Delete your Customer Master Access Key in your [Security Credentials](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential) page

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CloudTrail. It's on by default and it will track API calls. You most likely either have a badly configured autoscaling group, or your keys have been leaked. CloudTrail should tell you who is doing what.